# javascript: url in jquery html() in onmouseover in a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

This url throws a `missing ) after argument` error. It is being dynamically generated by PHP. I cannot figure out the correct sequence/placement of single and double quotes to render it.

```
<a href="cards.html" onmouseover="jQuery('.menu-image li').html('<img src='cards_1.png' />');">Cards</a>
```

The particular effect desired is to onmouseover insert an image into .menu-image li. All I can figure out is that the `img src` with the quotes (I've tried single and double) is not liked and throws the argument error.

Comment: Why are you adding jQuery inline?

Comment: I will probably end up not using inline now that I've got this working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try escaping the incorrect quotes with `\` or `\\`.

I.e. `html('<img src=\'cards_1.png\' />');`

Alternatively, you can just use `&quot;`. An URL encoder should have done this for you automatically.

A very popular error btw. is to not encode every `&` in an URL as `&amp;`. Browsers usually guess right what was intended though, so people never learn. But the link

```
<a href="test.php?a=1&b=2">example</a>
```

is actually incorrect and should be

```
<a href="test.php?a=1&amp;b=2">example</a>
```

Now if you had been using an **URL encoder** instead of just "printing" the string, it should automatically have converted your double quote to `&amp;` and probably saved you some headaches.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, &quot works great. I have in many years never come across the need to do that :)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you need to escape the innermost single quotes like so:

```
<a href="cards.html" onmouseover="jQuery('.menu-image li').html('<img src=\'cards_1.png\' />');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to write this:

```
<a href="cards.html" onmouseover="jQuery('.menu-image li').html('<img src=\'cards_1.png\' />');">Cards</a>
```

...otherwise your browser can't distinguish if the apostrophes belong to the `<img` tag or the `html(` command

Answer (score 2):

Use encoded quotes for the `<img/>` tag:

```
<a href="cards.html" onmouseover="jQuery('.menu-image li').html('<img src=&quot;cards_1.png&quot; />');">Cards</a>
```